# Mapping same local folder to different visual studio tfs instance

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, visual-studio-2017, source-control-explorer

I have already mapped a local folder C:/Projects to VS2015 TFS.

Now I have installed VS2017 on the same machine. So can i map the same local folder to VS2017 also ? If it is then what are the pros and cons doing this ?

Also, I found there is no project.json file available in VS2017 which is available in VS2015. So in this case if I do Get Latest Version(if local folder can be mapped to multiple Visual Studio instances) then there will be a problem ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we cannot map to the same local folder.

The VS clients can identify the workspaces which be created in both VS 2015 and VS 2017 in same machine. So, when we use VS 2017, we can select the workspace which is created in VS 2015 to track the projects, but cannot map other projects to the same local folder which already be mapped. Otherwise it will pop up the error message something like "`The path E:\Andy\0706 is already mapped in workspace LC0706.`"

We can only map to its sub folders if you want to map other sources to the specific local folder. eg : `E:\Andy\0706\subfolder`
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help !